# User is not created with spring security ui with email registration

Tags: grails, spring-security

In Spring security ui plugin/Registercontroller
i register with some login crendentials...the mail is sent to email....
the registration token and username is stored in registration _code table...
but the user is not created in sec_user table.

my code

```
   def register = { RegisterCommand command ->

    println("am before command")
    if (command.hasErrors()) {
        render view: 'index', model: [command: command]
        return
    }

    String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null :command.username
    //String password =    
         springSecurityService.encodePassword(command.password,salt)
    String password=command.password
    println("lookup userclas--------------"+lookupUserClass())
    def user = lookupUserClass().newInstance(email: command.email, username: 
               command.username,password: password, accountLocked: true, enabled: true)
    println("user objct is------------------"+user)
    if (!user.validate() || !user.save()) {
        // TODO
        println("user saved-------------"+user.save())
    }

    def registrationCode = new RegistrationCode(username: user.username).save()
    String url = generateLink('verifyRegistration', [t: 
         registrationCode.token])
    println("url is-----------"+url)

    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    def body = conf.ui.register.emailBody
    println("body is--------------"+body)
    if (body.contains('$')) {
        body = evaluate(body, [user: user, url: url])
    }
    mailService.sendMail {
        to command.email
        from conf.ui.register.emailFrom
        subject conf.ui.register.emailSubject
        html body.toString()
    }

    render view: 'index', model: [emailSent: true]
}
```

the user object is not created.....
the lookupUserclass(0 value  is Sec_User i am getting

Comment: Don't you need to implement something in the TODO section ? I can't see where the actual registering is done

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing

> user saved-------------

it means the save *failed*. And that's probably what your problem is. For some reason, you're not creating a valid user. For example, there is no email field in the base sec_user.